# SQL Check if a date exists between certain 2 dates

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have these tables

- Hotel (hotelNo, hotelName, city)
- Room (roomNo, hotelNo, type, price)
- Booking (hotelNo, guestNo, dateFrom, dateTo, roomNo)
- Guest(guestNo, guestName, guestAddress)

How can I list hotels and rooms that were not reserved on "1-Mar-2022"?

What I've tried so far:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Hotel h, Room r, Booking b
WHERE h.hotelNo = r.hotelNo 
  AND b.roomNo = r.roomNo
  ??? AND NOT (b.dateFrom and b.dateTo not contains ‘2022-03-01’) ???
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM Hotel h, Room r, Booking b
WHERE h.hotelNo = r.roomNo AND b.roomNo = r.roomNo
??? AND NOT (b.dateFrom and b.dateTo not contains ‘2022-03-01’)

Comment: Should it be `where h.hotelNo = r.hotelNo`?

Comment: i've corrected it

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `'2022-03-01' NOT BETWEEN b.dateFrom and b.dateTo`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM Hotel h,
JOIN  Room r  ON h.HotelNo=r.HotelNo
JOIN Booking b ON b.roomNo = r.roomNo
 WHERE '2022-03-01' NOT BETWEEN b.dateFrom and b.dateTo
```

Answer (score 0):

Range type available since 9.2! https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/rangetypes.html
Let's refactor using range based on manual tutorial.

```
CREATE EXTENSION btree_gist;
CREATE TABLE room_booking (
    hottelNO,
    guestNo,
    roomNo text,
    during daterange,
    EXCLUDE USING gist (roomNo WITH =, during WITH &&)
);
```

then

```
SELECT * FROM Hotel h,
JOIN  Room r  ON h.HotelNo=r.HotelNo
JOIN room_booking b ON b.roomNo = r.roomNo
 WHERE during @> '2022-03-01' is false;
```